# How to turn on/off the BlackBerry menu?

Tags: blackberry, menu

To start off, I have almost no experience with BB development. I do have experience with programming and iPhone dev.

I've just picked up a BlackBerry project from someone else and apparently, the application he made won't show a menu when pressing the BlackBerry key (the same menu where the Close key should be located). This means that the application cannot be closed.

So, how do you create/show/hide that BlackBerry menu from showing up? What objects should I be looking for in the BB documentation? Any links to this info would also be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: in screen class of your project can you check that you are using FullScreen or MainScreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `makeMenu()` method in the class that extends `MainScreen`:

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
    super.makeMenu(menu, instance); //Add default menu's such as "Close"
    //Here add your own menu items see docs for: net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the `public boolean onMenu(int instance)` has been overridden, meaning that the `makeMenu(menu, instance)` method never gets called.

Consider **either** removing the override and doing the menu logic within your overridden `protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance)` function, **or** calling `makeMenu(menu, instance)` from the `onMenu()` function.

See [Screen.onMenu()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onMenu%28int%29) or [MainScreen.makeMenu()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html#makeMenu%28net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Menu,%20int%29) in the API for more info.